# Is there an Full Text Search Limit in opengrok?

Tags: git, search, limit, opengrok

0.12.1.5 with a large Git Project with more than 700 Repos.
When performing a Full Text Search in about 50 Repos it works very well.
Beyond a certain number of Repos, opengrok just shows a white page, when clicking Search and no request nor log entry can be seen.

So is there a known limit?

Comment: it relies on the HTTP Header. https://github.com/OpenGrok/OpenGrok/wiki/How-to-install-OpenGrok#large-number-of-projects-on-tomcat

Answer (score 0):

OpenGrok stuffs the repositories you have selected into the query string, which means that depending on the browser you're using, there is a maximum number of repositories that you can search at the same time. In theory, a repository with a long enough *name* could be unsearchable.

I've heard of three workarounds to this problem:

1. Write a script that automates the process of "select N repos, search, select the next N repos, search, ....."
2. Group repositories together in folders on the file system of the server on which OpenGrok is installed - or, in other words, use the file system to create a hierarchical structure. The top-level folders will be searchable in OpenGrok's UI. This architectural 'pattern' has additional benefits - it can be used to group all of the repositories used by a particular team under the same search heading, for example.
3. Use [OpenGrok Groupings](https://github.com/OpenGrok/OpenGrok/wiki/OpenGrok-Groupings) to accomplish the same goal as in 2.

Regardless of the mechanism you choose, the end goal is to be able to squeeze all of the top-level search entries into the query string when you whack 'Select All' and search.